# Why no split function in C?

Tags: c, string, split

There is no Standard function in C to take a string, break it up at whitespace
or other delimiters, and create an array of pointers to `char`, in one step.
If you want to do that sort of thing, you have to do it yourself, either
completely by hand, or by calling e.g. `strspn` and `strpbrk` in a loop,
or by calling `strtok` in a loop, or by calling `strsep` in a loop.

I am not asking how to do this.  I [know how to do this](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html),
and there are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/) of
[other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319166/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177795/implementing-split-function-in-c)
on Stackoverflow
about how to do it.  What I'm asking is if there are any good reasons *why*
there's no such function.

I know the two main reasons, of course: "Because no mainstream compiler/library
ever had one" and "Because the C Standard didn't specify one, either (because
it likes to standardize existing practice)."  But are there any other reasons?
(Are there arguments that such a function is an actively bad idea?)

This is usually a lame and pointless sort of question, I know. In this case
I'm fixated on it because convenient splitting is such a massively useful
operation.  I wrote my own string splitter within my first year as a
C programmer, I think, and it's been a huge productivity enhancer for me ever
since.  There are dozens of questions here on SO every day that could be
answered easily (or that wouldn't even have to be asked) if there were a
standard split function that everyone could use and refer to.

To be clear, the function I'm imagining would have a signature like

```
int split(char *string, char **argv, int maxargs, const char *delim)
```

It would break up `string` into at most `maxargs` substrings, splitting on one or more characters from `delim`, placing pointers to the substrings into `argv`, and modifying `string` in the process.

And to head off an argument I'm sure someone will make: although it's standard, I do not consider
`strtok` to be an effective solution.  `strtok`, frankly, sucks.  Saying "you don't need a split function,
because `strtok` exists" is a lot like saying "You don't need `printf`,
because `puts` exists."  This is not a question about what's theoretically
possible with a given toolset; it's about what's useful and convenient.  The more
fundamental issue here, I guess, concerns the ineffable tradeoffs involved
in picking tools that are leverageable and productivity-enhancing and that
"pay their way".  (I think it's clear that a nicely encapsulated
string-splitting function would pay its way handsomely, but perhaps
that's just me.)

Comment: You could ask the same thing about why there's no `uppercase(char*)`. `toupper(char)` already exists and you can build your own `uppercase(char*)` with it. Same with `strtok` and your `split`. Obviously there are exceptions to this. But I feel that this question is pretty opinion-based.

Comment: I find the question very interesting, but I highly doubt that it exists an answer on the form *"That's because in 1986, they took a formal decision to not include such a function"*, so  I suspect that any answer will be highly speculative. Therefore I vote to close. Sorry.

Comment: @Kevin MSVC has `strupr` and `strlwr`. Any library is free to add utility functions. Another example is gcc's `strsep`.

Comment: Adding in such functionality into a language that does not even have a string type is pushing it:)

Comment: How about this analogy: "You don't need `scanf`, because `gets` exists."

Comment: What happens if the string contains more occurrences of the separator? This API does not seem easy to restart like `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try an answer. I indeed agree that such a function would be useful. It *is* often quite useful in the languages that have one.

Basically you are suggesting a very simple builtin wrapper around `strtok()` or `strtok_r()`. It would be a less powerful version (as we can't change the delimiter while processing) but still useful in some cases.

What I see is that these cases are also overlapping with `scanf()` family functions use cases and with `getopt()` or `getsubopt()` family functions use cases.

Actually I'm not sure that the remaining real use cases are that common.

In real life non trivial cases you would need a true parser or regex library, in specialized common case you already have `scanf()` or `getopt()` or even strtok().

Also functions *modifying* their input strings like `strtok()` or yours are more or less deprecated these days (experience says they easily lead to troubles).

Most languages providing a split feature have a real string type, often an immutable one, and are supporting it by creating many individual substrings while leaving the original string intact.

Following that path would lead to either some other API not based on zero delimited strings (maybe with a start pointer and an end pointer), or with allocated string copies (like when using `strdup()`). Neither really satisfying.

In the end, if you add up not so common use in real life, quite simple to write and not that simple or intuitive API, there is no wonder that such function wasn't included in strandard libc.

Basically I would write something like that:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int split(char *string, char **argv, int maxargs, const char *delim){
    char * saveptr = 0;
    int x = 0;
    argv[x++] = strtok_r(string, delim, &saveptr);
    while(argv[x-1] && (x <= maxargs)){
        argv[x++] = strtok_r(0, delim, &saveptr);
    }
    return x-1;
}

int main(){
    char * args[10];
    {
        char * str = strdup("un deux trois quatre cinq six sept huit neuf dix onze");
        int res = split(str, args, sizeof(args)/sizeof(char*), " ");
        printf("res = %d\n", res);
        for(int x = 0; x < res ; x++){
            printf("%d:%s\n", x, args[x]);
        }
    }

    {
        char * str = strdup("un deux trois quatre cinq");
        int res = split(str, args, sizeof(args)/sizeof(char*), " ");
        printf("res = %d\n", res);
        for(int x = 0; x < res ; x++){
            printf("%d:%s\n", x, args[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

What I see looking at the code is that the wanted function is really very simple to write using `strtok()`... and that the call site to use the result is nearly as complicated as the function itself. In such a case hencefore I'd rather inline the function on the call site than having to call libc.

But of course you are welcome to use and write yours if you believe it's simpler for you.