# Returning pointer to char* ruins data

Tags: c, split, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to write a function that will split a string along a space (`' '`) without changing the original string, put all of the tokens into an array, then return that array. The problem I am running into is in returning the pointer. Below is my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split_line(char *ln) {
    char **tokens, *tok, line[256];
    int j;

    strcpy(line, ln);

    tokens = calloc(64, sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        tokens[i] = calloc(64, sizeof(char));

    tokens[0] = strtok(line, " ");
    for (j = 1; (tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL && j < 63; j++) 
        tokens[j] = tok;
    tokens[j] = NULL;

    return tokens;
}

int main(void) {
    char **cut_ln, *input;

    input = "Each word in this string should be an element in cut_ln.";
    cut_ln = split_line(input);

    printf("`%s`\n", input);
    for (int i = 0; cut_ln[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("[%d]: `%s`\n", i, cut_ln[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, this gives:

```
`This word in this string should be an element in cut_ln.`
[0]: `This`
[1]: `wo1`
[2]: `�={G+s`
[3]: `G+s`
[4]: `string`
[5]: ``
[6]: `0����`
[7]: `��`
[8]: ``
[9]: ``
[10]: ``
```

When I try to print the contents of `tokens` in the `split_line` function, it gives the expected result. However, when `tokens` is returned and assigned to a variable, and then printed, it gives the result above as demonstrated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `tokens[j] = tok;` overwrites the pointer you so carefully allocated with `calloc`, leaking that memory.  Did you intend to write something like `strcpy(tokens[j], tok)` instead?

Comment: `strdup()` then `strok()`. Don't re-invent the wheel. If you do reinvent it, at least **count the number of entries first** in a quick scan, then allocate, then return. Don't just **assume** 64 will be enough. That will almost always be wrong. The number `64` has absolutely no reason to be here, you have nothing to back up why that number exists. It seems chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: I commend you for writing this function -- it's a great way to handle string input.  Wonderful to have in your toolkit.  (I wish there were a standard library function like this.)  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372173/why-no-split-function-in-c).

Comment: @tadman Did not know about `strdup`. However, [it would appear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252802/13821134) that it is not part of ISO C.

Comment: Unless you're specifically constrained by ISO C, as in you're on some limited platform, then sure, but otherwise, some degree of POSIX compliance virtually is a given, even on non-POSIX compliant platforms like Windows. When we talk about modern C we usually include POSIX as it's readily available just about everywhere. GCC, clang and VCC all support it. Some arcane C89 compiler for a long dead operating system might not, like I wouldn't count on it being present in Microsoft XENIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return `tokens`, it contains the pointers returned from `strtok`, which are pointers into `line`. But `line` no longer exists at this point.

You allocated memory and made the various elements of `tokens` point to that allocated memory. Don't overwrite those values with the values returned from `strtok`.

Comment: `line` fell out of scope, to be specific. It's just a ghost of a previous value at that point, and like a haunted string it does all sorts of spooky things.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
char ** split_line( const char *ln );
```

because the passed string is not being changed within the function.

The function will be a more flexible if to declare a second parameter that will specify delimiters.

```
char ** split_line( const char *ln, const char *delim );
```

Secondly it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `64` or `256`.  The function will not work if the passed string contains more than `63` tokens or when the string for example contains at least one token the length of which is greater than `63`.

You dynamically allocated 64 arrays in this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    tokens[i] = calloc(64, sizeof(char));
```

and assigned their addresses to elements of the array pointed to by the variable `tokens`. But at once you reassigned the pointers with addresses inside the local array `line`.

```
tokens[0] = strtok(line, " ");
for (j = 1; (tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL && j < 63; j++) 
    tokens[j] = tok;
```

So the function produces numerous memory leaks. And the returned array of pointers will contain invalid pointers because the local array `line` will not be alive after exiting the function.

Also this statement

```
tokens[j] = NULL;
```

is redundant. Using `calloc` you already set initially all pointers to `NULL`.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ** split_line( const char *s, const char *delim )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, delim );
        
        if ( *p )
        {
            ++n;
            p += strcspn( p, delim );
        }
    }
    
    char **tokens = calloc( n + 1, sizeof( char * ) );
    
    if ( tokens )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        int success = 1;
        
        for ( const char *p = s; success && *p; i += success )
        {
            p += strspn( p, delim );
        
            if ( *p )
            {
                const char *q = p;
                p += strcspn( p, delim );
                
                tokens[i] = malloc( p - q + 1 );
                
                if ( ( success = tokens[i] != NULL ) )
                {
                    memcpy( tokens[i], q, p - q );
                    tokens[i][p-q] = '\0';
                }
            }
        }
        
        if ( !success )
        {
            for ( char **p = tokens; *p; ++p )
            {
                free( *p );
            }
            
            free( tokens );
        }
    }
    
    return tokens;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Each word in this string should be an element in cut_ln.";
    
    char **tokens = split_line( s, " " );
    
    if ( tokens )
    {
        for ( char **p = tokens; *p; ++p )
        {
            puts( *p );
        }
        
        for ( char **p = tokens; *p; ++p )
        {
            free( *p );
        }
    }
    
    free( tokens );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Each
word
in
this
string
should
be
an
element
in
cut_ln.
```