# Splitting string into words in array without using any pre-made functions in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I am trying to create a function that takes a `string`, splits it into `words` and return an `array` with the `words` in it. I am not allowed to use any pre-made functions other than `malloc` within the `splitting` function. Finally I have to set my function in this form `char   **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)`
My current output looks like that:

```
    d this is me
    s is me
    s me
    r
```

Expected output:

```
    Hello
    World
    This
    Is
    Me
```

my full code is in the following codes:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int     count_words(char *str)
    {
        int i; 
        int word;
        
        i = 0;
        word = 1;
        while(str[i]!='\0')
        {
            if(str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\n' || str[i]=='\t' 
            || str[i]=='\f' || str[i]=='\r' || str[i]=='\v')
                word++;
            i++;
        }
        return (word);
    }
    
    char    **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)
    {
        int index;
        int size;
        int index2;
        char **arr;
        
        index = 0;
        index2 = 0;
        size = count_words(str);
        arr = (char **)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        if (arr == NULL)
            return ((char **)NULL);
        while (str[index])
        {
            if(str[index] == ' ')
            {
                index++;
                value++;
                index2++;
            }
            else
                *(arr+index2) = (char*) malloc(index * sizeof(char));
                *(arr+index2) = &str[index];    
            index++;
        }
        **arr = '\0';
        return (arr);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        char a[] = "Hello World This Is Me";
        char **arr;
        int i;
        int ctr = count_words(a);
        arr = ft_split_whitespaces(a);
        
        for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
            printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is a good question.  It's discussed in [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html).  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372173).

Comment: How is the code that calls `ft_split_whitespaces` supposed to know how many entries the returned array has? Is there supposed to be a `NULL` on the end? (If so, don't forget to allocate space for that pointer!)

Comment: Is `ft_split_whitespaces()` allowed to modify the original string (e.g. insert zero terminators at the end of words and return an array of pointers to the start of words, to avoid allocating memory for each word)?  You could possibly also use recursion to avoid `count_words()`.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return value of malloc if you are compiling with a C compiler: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#:~:text=In%20C%2C%20you%20don't,compiler%2C%20a%20cast%20is%20needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few errors in your program:

1. `arr = (char **)malloc(size * sizeof(char));` is not right since
   `arr` is of type `char**`. You should use `sizeof(char*)` or better
   `(sizeof(*arr))` since `sizeof(char)` is usually not equal to
   `sizeof(char*)` for modern systems.
2. You don't have braces `{}` around your `else` statement in
   `ft_split_whitespaces` which you probably intended. So your
   conditional logic breaks.
3. You are allocating a new `char[]` for every non--whitespace
   character in the `while` loop. You should only allocate one for
   every new word and then *just* fill in the characters in that array.
4. `*(arr+index2) = &str[index];`This doesn't do what you think it
   does. It *just points* the string at `*(arr+index2)` to `str` offset
   by `index`. You either need to copy each character individually or
   do a `memcpy()` (which you probably can't use in the question). This
   explains why your answer just provides offsets into the main string and
   not the actual tokens.
5. `**arr = '\0';` You will lose whatever you store in the `0th` index
   of `arr`. You need to individually append a `\0` to each string in
   `arr`.
6. `*(arr+index2) = (char*) malloc(index * sizeof(char));` You will end up
   allocating progressively increasing size of `char` arrays at because
   you are using `index` for the count of characters, which keeps on
   increasing. You need to figure out the correct length of each token in
   the string and allocate appropriately.

Also why `*(arr + index2)`? Why not use the much easier to read `arr[index2]`?

---

Further clarifications:

Consider `str = "abc de"`

You'll start with

```
*(arr + 0) = (char*) malloc(0 * sizeof(char));
//ptr from malloc(0) shouldn't be dereferenced and is mostly pointless (no pun), probably NULL
*(arr + 0) = &str[0];
```

Here `str[0] = 'a'` and is a location somehwhere in memory, so on doing `&str[0]`, you'll store that address in `*(arr + 0)`

Now in the next iteration, you'll have

```
*(arr + 0) = (char*) malloc(1 * sizeof(char)); 
*(arr + 0) = &str[1];
```

This time you replace the earlier malloc'd array at the same `index2` again with a different address. In the next iterations `*(arr + 0) =  (char*) malloc(2 * sizeof(char));`. You end up resetting the same `*(arr + index2)` position till you encounter a whitespace after which you do the same thing again for the next word. So don't allocate arrays for every `index` value but only if and when required. Also, this shows that you'll keep on increasing the size passed to `malloc` with the increasing value of `index` which is what #6 indicated.

Coming to `&str[index]`.

You are setting `(arr + index2)` i.e. a `char*` (pointer to `char`) to another `char*`. In C, setting a pointer to another pointer doesn't copy the contents of the second pointer to the first, but only makes both of them point to the same memory location. So when you set something like `*(arr + 1) = &str[4]`, it's just a pointer into the original string at `index = 4`. If you try to print this `*(arr + 1)` you'll just get a substring from `index = 4` to the end of the string, not the word you're trying to obtain.

`**arr = '\0'` is just dereferencing the pointer at `*arr` and setting its value to `\0`. So imagine if you had `*(arr + 0) = "hello\0"`, you'll set it to `"\0ello\0"`. If you're ever iterating over this string, you'll never end up traversing beyond the first `'\0'` character. Hence you lose whatever `*arr` was earlier pointing to.

Also, `*(arr + i)` and `arr[i]` are exactly equivalent and make for much better readability. It better conveys that `arr` is an array and `arr[i]` is dereferencing the `i`th element.

Comment: Thank you alot for your comment, but I have to admit starting from step 3 onwards I really didnt understand how I should tackle those problems, Have to say I am pretty new hands on with pointers and malloc, so if possible to clarify them more it would be great! Thanks anyway

Comment: @Alsakka I've added further explanation. Fix these and you should have a working solution. I'm not going to write the exact answer since that isn't what SO is for but I hope you're able to see and work the solution for yourself. You're on the right track. Good luck!